# How can I test the return value of a PL/SQL variable in ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, plsql, odp.net, data-access

I have this piece of code thta executes a PL/SQL:

```
        using (PedidoEntities db = new PedidoEntities())
        {
            OracleParameter p_existe = new OracleParameter("p_existe", OracleDbType.Int32);
            p_existe.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            OracleParameter p_modulo = new OracleParameter("p_modulo", OracleDbType.Int32);
            p_modulo.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; p_modulo.Value = (int)modulo;
            OracleParameter p_usuario = new OracleParameter("p_usuario", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            p_usuario.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; p_usuario.Value = usuario; p_usuario.Size = usuario.Length;
            string sql = @"begin
                             select 1 
                             into :p_existe
                             from PERMISOS P
                             inner join USUARIO U ON U.USUARIO = P.USUARIO
                             where P.MODULO = :p_modulo 
                                   and U.NOMBRE = :p_usuario;
                           exception
                             when no_data_found then
                               :p_existe := 0;
                           end;";
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, p_existe, p_modulo, p_usuario);
            return p_existe.Value.Equals(1);
        }
```

The problem is that the return value is an INT that I need to test against 1 or 0. I can just use p_existe.Value.ToString() and it works, however, I want to do the checking as a number since it is a number. How can I do it? Any cast I have tried does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Finall I have used this code:

```
return ((OracleDecimal)p_existe.Value).Value.Equals(1)
```

That works.